# KendoUI Grid Cell Template with promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, telerik

I have to use templates to translate my grid's cells values.

For some reasons, the function I'm calling to translate is returning a promise.

I found the following topic related to my issue

[Asynchronous cell template](http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-return-a-value-%28from-async-call%29-to-a-grid's-cell-template-)

I'm using the angular method with

> ng-bind-html

```
$scope.lookUpEventNameAsync = function(data) {

    refData.events().fetch(function() {
        var eData = refData.events().data();
        var refEvent = eData.find(function(re, i, a) {
            return re.code === data.eventCode;
        });
        $("#async_tse_" + data.key).html(refEvent.name);
    });

    return $sce.trustAsHtml("<div id='async_tse_" + data.key + "'> </div>");
};

$scope.gridTimesheetColumns = [
    {
        field: "eventCode",
        title: "Event", 
        template: "<span ng-bind-html='lookUpEventNameAsync(dataItem)'> </span>"
    },
....
```

I made a similar thing to adapt it with the code I have and it's working.

But the problem now is that it's calling `$scope.lookUpEventNameAsync` several times and never stop calling it which is freezing the screen and make the app unusable.

Do you have an idea why and how can I prevent it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed a one way data binding like the following :

```
$scope.gridTimesheetColumns = [
{
    field: "eventCode",
    title: "Event", 
    template: "<span ng-bind-html='::lookUpEventNameAsync(dataItem)'> </span>"
},
```